# Mapping C/C++ Data Type In C++/CLI

Tags: c++, c++-cli

I have to start the development of the C++/CLI Wrapper around Existing Static C Library. I Encountered number of enums, typedefs, and structs in the C Library. Since I am new to C++/CLI I wanted to know what data type can used in C++/CLI.

```cpp
typedef struct _GC_DEVICE {
    TCHAR *ptszDevicePath;

    /// The human-readable name of the device.
    /// This member is never NULL.
    TCHAR *ptszFriendlyName;

    //Device Type
    GC_DEVICE_TYPE DeviceType;

    /// USB related information about the camera.
    GC_USB_DEVICE_INFO USBDevInfo;

} GC_DEVICE,*PGC_DEVICE;

enum GC_DEVICE_TYPE {
    GC_USB_DEVICE,
    GC_IP_DEVICE,
    GC_DEPTH_SENSING_DEVICE,
};

typedef struct _GC_USB_DEVICE_INFO {
    /// The vendor ID.
    WORD    wVendor;
    /// The product ID.
    WORD    wProduct;
    /// The product revision number.
    WORD    wRelease;
} GC_USB_DEVICE_INFO, *PGC_USB_DEVICE_INFO;
```

Can Any Body Help Me Converting these declaration in C++/CLI?

Comment: Why using C++/CLI? Why not just using C# P/Invoke?

Comment: @Simon:Its Static C Library,So I think C# P/Invoke is only for  Dll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ref class GCDeviceWrapper
{
public:
    // operations with the GC_DEVICE instance

private:
    GC_DEVICE device_;
};
```